# How to set input tag between multiple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Suppose there are 2 forms in the same view, I wonder how to set input tags between the forms.
Like this.

```
= form_for @restaurant, url: {action: restaurant_path} do |r|
      = r.fields_for :restaurant_translations do |rt|
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restaurantname)
          dd = rt.text_field :restaurantname, autofocus: true, size: 120
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restauranttel)
          dd = rt.text_field :restauranttel, autofocus: true, size: 120
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restaurantaddr)
          dd = rt.text_field :restaurantaddr, autofocus: true, size: 120
      dl.field
        dt = r.label (t :url)
        dd = r.text_field :url
      dl.field
        dt = r.label (t :storehours)
        dd = r.text_field :storehours
```

Currently, the order is like this.

1. restaurantname
2. restauranttel
3. restaurantaddr
4. url
5. storehours

If possible, I'd like to set form order like this.

1. url
2. restaurantname
3. storehours
4. restauranttel
5. restaurantaddr

At the moment, it's too difficult to mix different form tag.
Does anyone know how? Let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple `fields_for` form helper,

```
    = form_for @restaurant, url: {action: restaurant_path} do |r|
      dl.field
        dt = r.label (t :url)
        dd = r.text_field :url
      = r.fields_for :restaurant_translations, @restaurant_translation do |rt|
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restaurantname)
          dd = rt.text_field :restaurantname, autofocus: true, size: 120
      dl.field
        dt = r.label (t :storehours)
        dd = r.text_field :storehours
      = r.fields_for :restaurant_translations, @restaurant_translation do |rt| 
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restauranttel)
          dd = rt.text_field :restauranttel, autofocus: true, size: 120
        dl.field
          dt = rt.label (t :restaurantaddr)
          dd = rt.text_field :restaurantaddr, autofocus: true, size: 120
```

from controller action build `@restaurant_translation` as

```
@restaurant_translation = @restaurant.restaurant_translations.build
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh. But unfortunately, that creates multiple record on restaurant_translations. So could you tell me how to avoid this problem?